# torch.cuda.device_count() returns 2, but torch.load(model_path, map_location='cuda:1') throws an error

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I have two GPUs and when I run

```
import torch
print('count: ', torch.cuda.device_count())  # prints count: 2
```

However, my model throws an error

```
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device 2 but torch.cuda.device_count() is 1
```

on the line

```
torch.load(model_path, map_location='cuda:1')
```

What could cause it and how to fix it?

This issue is somehow linked to my Flask, because the training itself works with `torch.load(model_path, map_location='cuda:1')`

Comment: Can you tell me which GPU you have trained your model on? Was it 'cuda:0' or 'cuda:1'? Or did you used both GPUs with data parallel?
The torch.load first deserializes the tensors on CPU and moves it to the specified device (the same device it was trained on)
Maybe specify the device like map_location = torch.device('cuda:1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Flask-CUDA issue. Please run Flask with it with
`print('count: ', torch.cuda.device_count())` and check if you see

```
count: 2
reloading
count: 1
```

If so, add `app.run(... , use_reloader=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You say:

```
print('count: ', torch.cuda.device_count())  # prints count: 2
```

But the error says:

```
torch.cuda.device_count() is 1
```

Could you confirm that your run the two in the same worker?

edit: According to the message I had when trying to assign in wrong GPU, it could be due to asynchronous process calls. You may debug with `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING']='1'`.